# How to create a select statement that satisifies multiple condition from a single column?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

Here I have 3 columns : ID(NUMBER),PART_NAME(VARCHAR) and PART_VALUE(CLOB)(All three forms a Primary Key). I'm having a scenerio in such a way that i should check multiple conditions for the same column.
For eg : For Particular ID, I Should check Different Part_Name and its corresponding part_value. The below is wrong i know. Just for reference i'm including

```
SELECT COUNT(0) 
FROM MY_TABLE  
WHERE ID = 'XYZ'
AND (
        (
            (
                PART_TYPE='SW NUT Prod' 
                AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'NUT and Non-Standard Key')=0
            ) 
        OR  
            (
                PART_TYPE='SW NUT Prod' 
                AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'LIMES Key and Document')=0
            ) 
        OR (
                PART_TYPE='SW NUT Prod' 
                AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'LIMES Physical Key and Document')=0
            )
        ) 
        AND (
            PART_TYPE='TRIM' 
            AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'FALSE')=0
        ) 
)
```

We have to acheive this. I have tried using self joints. But that didn't helped because we have very big queries wher we are supposed to check for 10 Part_name at a time.Any suggesstion would help me

Comment: We'll need more info... What does your referenced query produce? What do the tables look like? Can you rig up a sqlfiddle showing basic table data?

Comment: I will take the count from my reference query and based on the value, i have to do to different operations. Sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0e4e8)

Comment: So is this something the `having` clause could perform?

Comment: Having clause can't help i guess. It has to satisfy all the conditions..

Comment: Why can't you use the `having` clause with your `where` conditions?

Comment: If i use `having` i should use `group by` also na..i can't group by ID or part_name.i think i'm not getting ur suggestion. can you please post the query if u don't mind.

Comment: So you want to check for what again? And you want to return what again? I guess I'm kind of confused because your fiddle doesn't even have a `PART_TYPE` column.

Comment: Oops. i'm terribly sorry..Typing mistake.PART_NAME is supposed to be PART_TYPE. New link :[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/858e76) : I just want to check multiple condition on same column . here i want the count . Count will be `0` if any of the conditions doesn't satisfy and it will be `1` if all the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Should `AND ( PART_TYPE='TRIM' AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'FALSE')=0 )` be `OR ( PART_TYPE='TRIM' AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'FALSE')=0 )` - otherwise you will never match any rows (since you are currently looking for `PART_TYPE='TRIM' AND PART_TYPE='SW NUT Prod'` which will always be false). [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/858e76/2)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MTO : If i use `OR` there it will not give proper output. SQLfiddle :  [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/858e76/5). If u see here i'm giving OR and giving `( PART_TYPE='TRIM' AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'TRUE')=0 )` . i'm giving true instead of false. But count is still `1' which means it s not bothering about the last condition. and Yes u r correct. If i use above statement it will always be false. Actually that s my problem. we can't use same column name multiple times at the same time in where condition. I'm looking for some alternative from what i have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These query may help. It adds column `cnt` to each row in table, which informs if all conditions for this id were satisfied:

```
with data as (  
  SELECT id, part_type, part_value,  
      case when PART_TYPE='SW NUT Prod' 
        and (DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'NUT and Non-Standard Key')=0 
          or DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'LIMES Key and Document')=0 
          or DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'LIMES Physical Key and Document')=0) 
        then 1 end c1,
      case when PART_TYPE='TRIM' AND DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(PART_VALUE,'FALSE')=0 
        then 1 end c2
    FROM MY_TABLE)
select id, part_type, part_value, case when c1 > 0 and c2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end cnt  
  from (
    select id, part_type, part_value,
        count(c1) over (partition by id) c1, count(c2) over (partition by id) c2 
      from data)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64e7de/1)</sup>

For some reason you don't want `group by`, but of course you can simplify output using this clause. 
If you are interested only in particular id add `where id=XYZ` in first subquery. In SQLFiddle I added second ID, 
where not all conditions have been met.

Comment: Thank you so much ponder. Only one small problem. I Just want one single ouput so that i can proceed further easily. This query is giving me all the rows. Can u please help me. Also please let me know how `group by` will help because i might have tried differently which led me to some performance issue

Comment: This is very small modification, add `where` in first subquery and `distinct` in main query like in the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64e7de/6).

Comment: -Thank you. It solved my issue. Can you please let me know how to use `group by` in this context. If I use `group by` id, i'm not getting the desired o/p. Should i group by c1,c2,c3 also? @Ponder

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You could use `group by`, but `distinct` is better - more readable and shorter. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64e7de/13) with examples.